# Most efficient way to split List<Object []> into List<String>

Tags: java, list, arraylist

Hi all  I am using JPA and have queries like this one below:

```
Select emp.aid, emp.surname from employees emp
```

The query stores the records in the `List<Object []>` list.

If emp.aid is a long integer and emp.surname is a String, what is the most efficient way to get two lists from the result. One a `List<Integer>` and the second `List<String>`

The order in both must stay in sync during the splitting process.   What is the most efficient way performance wise to go this?

Comment: Efficient in what way?

Comment: memory-efficient? performant? least amount of code? something else?

Comment: Performance wise sorry for leaving that out.

Comment: There aren't many ways to do that. Just do it with the simplest way you can imagine, and it will be fast enough. The time needed to do that is tiny compared to the time it takes to execute the query in the first place. Don't be so obsessed with performance. Make your code simple, readable and correct. For example, the query should be `select employee.aid, employee.surname from Employee employee`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't have two lists that have associated elements, rather create an `Employee` class with two fields (`id`, `surname`) and instead of storing each record returned from the query into a `Object[]` construct a new `Employee` object for each record returned providing the appropriate data.

This way you don't even need to deal with the complexity of dealing with  `List<Object[]>` and then ensuring that when this is split into two lists of different types that also each `id` of the Integer list must but at the same position as the `name` in the String list.

However, if you wish to proceed with your current approach you can do something like:

```
List<Integer> idList = tempList.stream()                                   
                               .map(e -> (Integer)e[0]).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

and the corresponding names:

```
List<String> nameList = tempList.stream()                                  
                                .map(e -> (String)e[1]).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

where `tempList` is defined as `List<Object[]> tempList`.

Comment: The instanceof check is useless, would hide a bug rather than reveal it, and has the nasty effect of removing null values from the list.

Comment: @JBNizet I assumed he would have constructed an Integer object to hold the ids and Strings to hold the names but thinking about it again you're correct. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed information @Aominè. Would select employee from Employees be sufficient to get Employee classes as query results? And then I access them via the normal getters and setters? I am new to JPA SQL sorry.

Comment: @georgelappies if you're going to proceed with the constructing an `Employee` class approach then I'd create a constructor which takes two parameters `id` and `name` and then create private fields to store these two parameters passed in. then you can create your readonly getters for them.

Comment: Thanks @Aominè I will go that route. Is the JPA SQL correct though as listed above?

Comment: @georgelappies there is no such thing as JPA SQL. Either it's a normal, JPQL query, or it's a native, SQL query. There is no reason to use a native query, especially for something that simple. And JPQL works on entities and their properties. Your entity is, or at least should be, named Employee, not employees.